# Online tools for ordering FTSE by P/E

Tags: shares

I'm looking for a way select the first 15 shares in each sector in the FTSE, ordered by P/E.

Are there any online tools that can provide this information?

Comment: i found what i was after here. http://shares.telegraph.co.uk/stockscreener/

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, there is this tool here: http://shares.telegraph.co.uk/stockscreener/.